# How do simple message protocols function?

Tags: java, protocols

I am confused how simple message protocols work.  I understand the basics of a 3 way handshake checksums, and the like, but from an implementation perspective how do I know if what I am reading is what I should be reading?

When I'm programming a thread to read the input stream of a socket, are there any guarantees? Should each message I send have an ID described from the previous message so I know I am receiving them in order?  How can I detect when a message is missed (such as the very last message) so that I am not sitting and waiting for a message that will never come (should I just use simple timeouts)?

Tips on what to search would also be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

TCP sockets guarantee that packets come in the right order. If you look at the headers of a TCP packet, you will notice they have a sequence number. If you are re-implementing TCP over UDP, you will need to provide some of these features yourself.

You should not need to detect if a message has been missed (received 1 and 3 but not 2).

Sockets can be closed unexpectedly though. If a computer goes offline then you aren't going to receive any other packets and there is no time for it to send a warning. Ping/Pong message are often used to make sure both ends are still communicating. Timeouts are your other option.

Are you talking protocols such as [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) (a good low level read)?

Or are you building a chat protocol? [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP) might be a good read for you.